# Timeout waiting to lock journal cache. It is currently in use by another Gradle instance

Tags: gradle

When I try to run many Gradle projects simultaneously I got following error:

```
Timeout waiting to lock journal cache (/Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/journal-1). It is currently in use by another Gradle instance.
              Owner PID: 1750
              Our PID: 1763
              Owner Operation: 
              Our operation: 
              Lock file: /Users/myusername/.gradle/caches/journal-1/journal-1.lock
```

I tried to run it in IntelliJ as well as in terminal (I don't work in Android Studio). I work on MacBook. I tried following:

- ./gradlew --stop
- remove all ".lock" file from .gradle directory
- remove .gradle directory

Any ideas how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

#### Option 1

```
pkill -f gradle
```

#### Option 2

```bash
killall -9 java
```

#### Option 3 (only works for the same version of Gradle)

```bash
./gradlew --stop
```

Answer (score 0):

Several Gradle processes cannot be run simultaneously. Here is the bug request about that:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/issues/8750